# how to make a colormap of an existing dataframe by adding additional dataset?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, multidimensional-array, seaborn

I have a dataframe look like a matrix, in which values varies from 0-15, I want to represent another dataset as another dimension of the existing data. This new data set has to give the colormap to the current heatmap plot. How to do it? I am giving a sample code below,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns


#first data
df = pd.read_csv('/Linux/Case_study/IncandMass.csv', delimiter=",", header=None,skiprows=1)  
df.info()
```

```
Out[64]: 
         0         1         2     ...      1436      1437      1438
174  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
173  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
172  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
171  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
170  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
..        ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
9    0.037891  0.051185  0.026712  ...  0.042928  0.055719  0.051363
8    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
7    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
6    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
5    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000

[170 rows x 1439 columns]
```

```
#Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 7))
# Displaying dataframe as an heatmap
sns.heatmap(df, cmap="jet", linewidths=0.0)
```

Here I imported my second dataset with the same shape

```
num = pd.read_csv('/Linux/Case_study/Incandnum.csv', delimiter=",", header=None,skiprows=1)
df.info()
```

I want to use this second dataset (num) for the colormap to use in the heatmap of the first dataset(df). How to do that?

Updated
The annot giving such outputs

```
sns.heatmap(da, cmap="jet", linewidths=0.0,annot = num)
```

I tried with other colormaps as well, it giving distorted images
[image]

Comment: You can use another dataframe for `annot=`.  E.g. `sns.heatmap(df, cmap="turbo", annot=num)`.  Note that the `jet` colormap has a very bad reputation, as it attracts attention to the wrong highlights.  Please note that `170 rows x 1439 columns` will be too many to show readable annotations.

Comment: @JohanC   sns.heatmap(da, cmap="jet", linewidths=0.0,annot = num) was giving a distorted figure as given in the last update in the question. I tried with different colormaps as well. Everything gave a distorted version